# How to Get total number of bytes copied by SCP

Tags: shell-script, shell, scp

I want to know total size of copied data from two different locations to another server using `scp`:

```
scp  /../folder1  /../folder2 srv2:/output/
```

---

```
Sending file modes: C0777 1049 file1 
Sink: C0777 1049 file1 file2 
Sending file modes: C0644 722 file2 file2 
Sink: C0644 722 file2 ........................................ 
Transferred: sent 4632, received 2128 bytes, in 0.6 seconds Bytes per second: sent 7810.4, received 3588.2 debug1: Exit status 0
 ==============================================
```

file1 = 1049 bytes

file2 = 722 bytes

TOTAL should be: 1771 bytes

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `-v` flag to be more verbose. This also prints the number of sent/received bytes to stderr before the command finishes.

As an example, this copies two 1MB files to the destination:

```
$ scp -v -r dir1 user@host:/tmp/
...
Entering directory: D0775 0 dir1
Sink: D0775 0 dir1
Sending file modes: C0664 1048576 file1
Sink: C0664 1048576 file1
file1                                                                                                                      100% 1024KB  22.5MB/s   00:00
Sending file modes: C0664 1048576 file2
Sink: C0664 1048576 file2
file2                                                                                                                      100% 1024KB  29.3MB/s   00:00
Sink: E
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2102108, received 2940 bytes, in 0.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2846707.3, received 3981.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```